# Could not import 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, importerror, django-oauth

It's the first time I work with django rest and Django Oauth toolkit
I'm following this tutorial 
[oauth2-with-django-rest-framework](https://yeti.co/blog/oauth2-with-django-rest-framework/)
But when I run python manage.py migrate I get the following error:

ImportError: Could not import 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: No module named ext.rest_framework.

What is going wrong ? is there another module I should install ? 
my virtual environment contains :

certifi==2017.4.17

chardet==3.0.4

Django==1.11.2

django-extensions==1.8.1

django-oauth-toolkit==1.0.0

djangorestframework==3.6.3

idna==2.5

oauthlib==2.0.2

pytz==2017.2

requests==2.18.1

six==1.10.0

Unidecode==0.4.21

urllib3==1.21.1

Comment: please show your settings file

Comment: settings files contains : INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'business',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_extensions',
    'oauth2_provider',
] for the installed aps and REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}
for the django rest settings

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It looks like `oath2_provider.ext` [has been moved](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/commit/cdc00603e738fdf78a217754196113cadc000f4f) to `oauth_provider.contrib`. You could try installing an older version of `django-oauth-toolkit`, or try changing the value in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` from:

```
'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
```

to:

```
'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
```

Note that the tutorial is a couple of years old, you might find other problems like this.

Comment: They should update their documentation https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Comment: @RohitSthapit 'they' might never see that comment. Instead of complaining here, why not create a pull request with updated instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue. In my setting file DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES was already 
**'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',**

I just installed older version as @Alasdair ask. My issue resolved. thanks