# python manage.py createsuperuser error import

Tags: python, django

When i try to use the command `python manage.py create superuser`, it is showing me error. Any help is much appreciated.

```
ImportError: Could not import 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: No module named ext.rest_framework.
```

Ubuntu 16

Comment: how could we help you without the source code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029183/could-not-import-oauth2-provider-ext-rest-framework-oauth2authentication-for-a

Comment: try with python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 0):

You need to install django rest framework using pip3 (pip for python 3):

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
```

Instructions on how to install pip3 can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

You can try by installing an older version of django-oauth-toolkit, or try it by changing the value in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES from:

'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',

to:

'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',

Comment: DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES - where i can find it? Where it is located?

Comment: Or how i can install older version?

Comment: you can install by this command : pip install django-oauth-toolkit

Comment: You can refer this link : http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html